# How to reset Wi-Fi location history

Tags: iphone, wifi, gps

If I have understood correctly, iPhones use Wi-Fi points to locate themselves more quickly.

I was working in one location and my company has now moved to a different location. I guess they brought the Wi-Fi equipment with them. When I now open Google Maps, it locates me at the location where my company was before we moved. Even when I switch of my Wi-Fi, it seems to think I am at this other location. This is Extremely annoying.

Is there a way to fix this? Can I reset the cache or Wi-Fi location history or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is called A-GPS (a for assisted)

I would try to **Reset Network Settings**.

Comment: yeah, and do this first @Svish !

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is actually something with their network. I had this issue when I was at Apple. They brought in a bunch of Cisco equipment that was configured in California to our store in Georgia and the location data always said it was still in California until they reset this on the network. Try testing it out on someone else's phone and see what happens. I'd ask your network administrator if this is something that can be changed.